# How to make a function repeat itself

Tags: python

I have a python problem, I'm reading from XML and have two spread functions set up; one finds a location, than the other function finds a location inside the first one, and returns info. my problem is that i need this to continue down the page and find other occurrences of each. I'm not sure if thats a good explanation of now so heres code:

```
def findEntryTag(webPage):
 start= webPage.find("<entry>") +7
 end= webPage.find("</entry>")
 slicedString=webPage[start:end]
 return slicedString

def findEarthquake(webPage):
 slicedString=findEntryTag(webPage)
 start= slicedString.find("<title>") +7
 end= slicedString.find("</title>")
 eq= slicedString[start:end]
 return eq

my Earthquake= findEarthquake(text)
print (myEarthquake)
```

so need it to do the functions again to get another earthquake and print out the hole list of them. please help! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lxml.etree makes this nice to work with.

For an XML document structured as so:

```
<entry>
    <title>story 1</title>
    <text>this is the first earthquake story</text>
    <title>story 2</title>
    <text>this is the second earthquake story</text>
    <title>story 3</title>
    <text>this is the third earthquake story</text>
</entry>
```

You can use lxml.etree like this to parse it:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.parse("test.xml")

for element in root.iter("title"):
    print("%s - %s" % (element.tag, element.text))
```

(from the example at http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)

The result looks like this:

```
title - story 1
title - story 2 
title - story 3
```

Season to taste!

Answer (score 5):

Don't try and parse XML manually. There are plenty of good ways of doing it, including `ElementTree` in the standard library.

Comment: ElementTree is great! also xml.sax is a good tool in the standard library